# Next js 13 Project is very slow to save file and showing intellisense suggestions in VScode

Tags: performance, next.js, next.js13, app-router, i3

After **npm run dev** my next js server started with fast refresh rate then i opened in browser and when i write the code on Vs Code then autocomplete, intellisense not working after sometimes my vscode automatically not responding and close the vscode, so many try to find the solution but can't find the solution please anyone provide the solution..

My Laptop configuration:
i3 6th gen 2.0ghz processor
8gb 2133mhz RAM
250gb ssd

Comment: If anyone facing the same problem so i suggest use  [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com) code editor same as it is VSCode. I think it will be solve your next js project related issue